# does grub-set-default do nothing without GRUB_DEFAULT=saved?

Tags: debian, grub

I'm dual-booting windows 11 with debian 11, and was trying to set the default grub choice at boot from the latter to the former. Looking around, I found `grub-reboot`, which the manual said only set the default for the next book, and a more promisingly named `grub-set-default`. I then did `grub-set-default 2` and was confused that the command didn't seem to make any changes to `/etc/default/grub` nor anything in `/boot/grub`, though I ran `update-grub` anyway. When I rebooted, the above seemed to have done nothing.

I looked in the manpage for `grub-set-default`, and noticed it said:

> Set  the  default  boot  menu  entry  for  GRUB.  This requires setting GRUB_DEFAULT=saved in /etc/default/grub.

Of course, I have `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` in that file, since that was what came with Debian. This is quite surprising, does this mean that `grub-set-default` really does nothing if I don't have `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` in `/etc/default/grub`, then did `update-grub`. Then I did `grub-set-default 2` again, and now when I reboot, it always defaults to entry 2, even if I selected 0 last time.

Of course, this behavior is what I initially wanted, but this is somewhat frustrating, as `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` has two different meanings: without `grub-set-default`, it means "have grub always default to the entry chosen last time". **With** `grub-set-default 2`, it means "have grub always default to 2, and both are necessary for this to happen.

[The Grub 2.06 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html) hints at this:

> GRUB_DEFAULT
>
> The default menu entry. This may be a number, in which case it identifies the Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero, or
> the title of a menu entry, or the special string 'saved' ... If you set this to 'saved', then the default menu entry will be that saved by ‘GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT’ or grub-set-default.